# How to take a file CSV upload in Rails 5+ and process it in a background job without losing it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, heroku

So from a rails controller, I save an ExcelSpreadsheet model that takes a CSV file upload from a form and puts it in the `attachment` attribute accessor.

Is there an easy way to do "process_csv" in a background job without losing the CSV attachment?  I'm on the Heroku platform as well, so I don't think I can store the attachment anywhere without using something like S3.

```
require 'csv'
class ExcelSpreadsheet
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :attachment

  validates :attachment, presence: true

  def save
    if valid?
     process_csv
    end
  end

  def process_csv
    CSV.foreach @attachment.path, headers: true do |row|
     #some stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Heroku allows uploads.  You may need to set up an S3 storage location.  Use carrierwave or paperclip gem.

Comment: @Swards - thanks, I clarified a bit - I was trying to see if I could use a background job without having to resort to S3, as then I'd want to protect the CSV as it contains sensitive data.

Comment: Store it in your database then (if it allows storage of big text blobs)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - We are running postgres - but isn't that "bad form" to store a big blob of text that you only really need for one time use?

Comment: You don't have many options. Basically, you have to store it _somewhere_. And it's not heroku filesystem. I personally use S3 for these things.

Comment: "only really need for one time use" - sooo, delete it afterwards?